# Concatenating values to List in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a List `a = [1, 2]` in groovy. I'm passing this as a parameter to a method and doing an `a.add(3)`. This is adding the element at the end. But someone else is accessing the same array elsewhere and i do not want them to see any changes i make to this array. I came to know that we can pass arrays only as references (correct me if i'm wrong).

However, in JavaScript we have something like `arr = [1, 2]` and `arr.concat(3)` - this returns an array `[1, 2, 3]` but if we print `arr`, it still prints `[1, 2]`.

Please let me know if there is any way to achieve this in groovy.

Comment: a = [1,2] doesn't create an array, it creates a list, specifically a java.util.ArrayList (confusing because the analogous thing in Ruby is called an Array, but in Groovy and Java there is something else called an array)

Comment: @NathanHughes Question updated ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use plus for this, as it creates a new list:

```
def a = [ 1, 2 ]
def b = a + 3

assert a == [1, 2]
assert b == [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add lists together to concatenate.  I prefer this to '+'ing a single element since everything has consistent types (List -> List -> List), so it still works if the 'element' you want to add is itself a collection.

```
def a = [ 1, 2 ]
def b = a + [3]

assert a == [1, 2]
assert b == [1, 2, 3]

def c = a + [[3, 4]]
assert c == [1, 2, [3, 4]]
```